# Is there any way to combine multiple images on the fly and download

Tags: php, image-processing, pagespeed

Is there any way to compress/combine multiple images on the fly so that the browser has to download one single file. And after download is finished then uncompress using JavaScript and then display on the page.

I know about css sprites. They are good for buttons, icons, small images. But I want to have a feature which will compress on demand and I could use it for miscellaneous images, gallery images too.

I have asked the same questions here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83895/is-there-any-way-to-combine-multiple-images-on-the-fly-and-download/83898?noredirect=1#comment100934_83898

But I haven't got satisfying answer. Any suggestion/idea is appreciated.

Comment: normally people put compression in their images ea use jpg or png files.
There is not much compression gain with gzip after you did proper image compression. - I'm only guessing but perhaps you want to know more about preloading images for websites, thats a different subject though

Comment: The purpose for which I mentioned compression is to bundle multiple image into a single file. Compression is not my main concern here, I know jpeg/png are already compressed well enough.

Comment: i've not come across anything what you mention, alternative you might create your own. Not sure what the gain of it would be (one wouldnt like to slow down a webserver, or a client), maybe you should look at http compression (although thats for whole documents), perhaps store images /write a service) that offers compressed html for images, start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Comment: The main targets is reducing the no. of hits to be made to the server for each image. Like we do using css sprites.

Comment: are hits a problem or the total data-bandwidth usage of your server ?.
If the later i would go for http compression, (and better pre compress images by different jpg / png compresssion, there optimizers for that), or consider a faster server, as hitcount is normally not a problem for a good working webserver.

Comment: The problem I asked was only related to hits. For other issues I have already found solutions. Thanks.